# Get input and output of a webservice?

Tags: web-services, soa

I am new to using webservices and i need to find out the input and output of a webservice.
I have the WSDL of the webservice and the XSD files.
Is there a script or a utility that I could use to get the list of input fields that a webservice requires and the output fields that it will return?

I tried using soapUI and by checking Request 1 i see all the fields of the webservice, but i dunno how i could tell which ones are input and which ones are output.

Any pointers on this are very much appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

Thats just the design view of a WSDL file in eclipse!